# confirm/ match account number. this is the regex ^[0-9]{7,12}$ that I validates the account number but I can not figure out how to confirm it

Tags: regex, match

I'm a real newbie -  I'm learning but it's hard for me so if you would help I would greatly appreciate it! I'm trying to confirm or match account number this is the regex ^[0-9]{7,12}$ that I validates the account number but I can not figure out how to confirm it

Comment: Use http://regex101.com to check your patterns like that.

Comment: I'm sorry I have looked there I am so new I just don't even understand how this all works I know this has been asked in different ways I just don't understand how to apply the answers when they are different